# TypeError: Cannot read property 'attempt1' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

We have this code below that basically has ng-change that trigger to changeValue() to recalculate the sum up of each attempt1 to attempt9.

But has the following error on **TypeError: Cannot read property 'attempt1' of undefined**. I believe this something to do with child/parent $scope accessible ... but not sure how to solve this.

BTW ... we are utilising AngularJS and Ionic Framework.

```js
.controller('RoutineActivityEditController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', '$localStorage', '$ionicPopup', function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $localStorage, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.apiurl = $localStorage.apiurl;

    $scope.options = [ {label: "Not Ok", value: 0},
                        {label: "ok", value: 1}
                     ];

    $http.get($scope.apiurl + '/routineactivity/' + $stateParams.uuId).success(function(data) {

      $scope.routineActivityData = data;

      $scope.total = $scope.routineActivityData.total;
      $scope.target = $scope.routineActivityData.target;

       // Debug JSON
        //console.log('TEST2:' + data);
        //$scope.showValues = JSON.stringify(data);
        //console.log('TEST3:' + $scope.showValues);

        $scope.changeValue = function ($scope)
        {
           $scope.total = $scope.routineActivity.attempt1.value;

           //+ $scope.routineActivity.attempt2 +
           //                $scope.routineActivity.attempt3 + $scope.routineActivity.attempt4 +
           //                $scope.routineActivity.attempt5 + $scope.routineActivity.attempt6 +
           //               $scope.routineActivity.attempt7 + $scope.routineActivity.attempt8 +
           //                $scope.routineActivity.attempt9; 
        }
    });
```

```html
<form name="routineActivityForm" ng-submit="sendData()">
<div ng-if="routineActivityData.item.routine.maxnoofattempt == 10">

          <div class="item item-input">Total: {{ total }} </div>
          <div class="item item-input">Target: {{ target }}</div>

          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">Attempt #1</div>
            <select name="attempt1" ng-model="routineActivity.attempt1" ng-change="changeValue()" ng-options="option.value as 
            option.value for option in options" ng-init="routineActivity.attempt1=routineActivityData.attempt1"> 
            </select>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">Attempt #2</div>
            <select name="attempt2" ng-model="routineActivity.attempt2" ng-change="changeValue()" ng-options="option.value as 
            option.value for option in options" ng-init="routineActivity.attempt2=routineActivityData.attempt2"> 
            </select>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">Attempt #3</div>
            <select name="attempt3" ng-model="routineActivity.attempt3" ng-change="changeValue()" ng-options="option.value as 
            option.value for option in options" ng-init="routineActivity.attempt3=routineActivityData.attempt3"> 
            </select>
            <!--<select name="attempt3" ng-model="routineActivity.attempt3" ng-change="changeValue()">
              <option ng-repeat="v in [0,1]" value="{{v}}" ng-selected="v==routineActivityData.attempt3">{{v}}</option> 
            </select>-->
          </label>    
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">Attempt #4</div>
            <select name="attempt4" ng-model="routineActivity.attempt4" ng-change="changeValue()" ng-options="option.value as 
            option.value for option in options" ng-init="routineActivity.attempt4=routineActivityData.attempt4"> 
            </select>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">Attempt #5</div>
            <select name="attempt5" ng-model="routineActivity.attempt5" ng-change="changeValue()" ng-options="option.value as 
            option.value for option in options" ng-init="routineActivity.attempt5=routineActivityData.attempt5"> 
            </select>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">Attempt #6</div>
            <select name="attempt6" ng-model="routineActivity.attempt6" ng-change="changeValue()" ng-options="option.value as 
            option.value for option in options" ng-init="routineActivity.attempt6=routineActivityData.attempt6"> 
            </select>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">Attempt #7</div>
            <select name="attempt7" ng-model="routineActivity.attempt7" ng-change="changeValue()" ng-options="option.value as 
            option.value for option in options" ng-init="routineActivity.attempt7=routineActivityData.attempt7"> 
            </select>
          </label>    
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">Attempt #8</div>
            <select name="attempt8" ng-model="routineActivity.attempt8" ng-change="changeValue()" ng-options="option.value as 
            option.value for option in options" ng-init="routineActivity.attempt8=routineActivityData.attempt8"> 
            </select>
          </label>    
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">Attempt #9</div>
            <select name="attempt9" ng-model="routineActivity.attempt9" ng-change="changeValue()" ng-options="option.value as 
            option.value for option in options" ng-init="routineActivity.attempt9=routineActivityData.attempt9"> 
            </select>
          </label>                   
        </div>
                
        <button class="button button-full button-positive">Save</button>
        <label >RESPONSE: {{ PostDataResponse  }}</label>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: why do you have `ng-init` for each `select` tag?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin is correct..those `ng-init` will do nothing.. basically there are going to evaluate expression before ajax response come

Comment: @ShaohaoLin - I need to set the selected dropdownlist from the remote API. It seems that this is the only way to make it selected and it works in my end :) Anyway ... the issue is that to getting the right $scope to do the changeValue